# Using mapping when applying a linear model to specified variables

Tags: r

I wish to perform a linear model, such that for my `n` covariates, it runs `n` times for `y ~ x1`, ..., `y ~ xn`. I have done it with a for loop and so I was intrigued at getting it to work with mapping.

For example, the `map` function has an example where it runs a linear model for `mpg ~ wt` for each of the factor levels of the variable `cyl`. This then gives three linear models - one for each of the factor levels of `cyl`:

```
library(purrr)

mtcars %>%
  split(.$cyl) %>%
  map(~ lm(mpg ~ wt, data = .x))
```

What if instead, I wished to use the `map` function to run a linear model for certain variables (e.g., say I have a vector with "cyl" and "wt" in it, and I wished to run `lm(mpg ~ cyl)` and then `lm(mpg ~ wt)`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `map2` to pass a `vector` having the same length as the length of the `list`

```
library(tidyverse)
mtcars %>%
  group_split(cyl) %>%
  map2(., c("cyl", "wt", "drat"), ~ lm(paste0("mpg ~ ", .y), data = .x))
```

or use `reformulate`

```
mtcars %>%
   group_split(cyl) %>%
   map2(., c("cyl", "wt", "drat"), ~ lm(reformulate(.y, "mpg"), data = .x))
```

---

If the intention is to have multiple `lm` for each `list` element

```
mtcars %>%
    group_split(cyl) %>% 
    map(~  {
          data = .x
           map(c("cyl", "wt"), ~ lm(reformulate(.x, "mpg"), data = data))
        })
```

Comment: Any idea how to keep the names of the split/groups with the output? I see there's this method: https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/4223#issuecomment-469269857 but feels complex? Especially when there's multiple groups.

Comment: @JasonAizkalns  `split` should keep it `mtcars %>% split(.$cyl)` there are no params in `group_split` to do it

Comment: @JasonAizkalns Otherwise, you need to use `keep = TRUE` `mtcars %>%
+     group_split(cyl, keep = TRUE) %>% map(~ .x$cyl)`